# Tomcat + Jboss application

Tags: web-applications, tomcat7, jboss7.x

For a java web application project we have identified tomcat7 as web server and jboss (version 7.1) as the application server. For development environment, both will run in the same machine. My question is what are the configuration which needs to be done for such a setup?

The web application uses JSF with prime faces at the presentation layer and spring for business layer

Comment: Do you mean using tomcat7 as the frontend webserver? can you elaborate  more on this?

Comment: Yes tomcat will be the front-end web server and jboss will act as my application server. Need to know about the web and app server configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat is a servlet engine not just a simple web server. [JBoss AS](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/) already provides a servlet engine as part of the Java EE specifications. There is no need to run both together. In fact JBoss AS uses [JBossWeb](http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/) which is based on Tomcat.

If you're looking for a web server for the front end [Apache HTTPD](http://httpd.apache.org/) is probably the way to go, though it's not really needed.

Comment: Is JBossWeb still alive? The last release was 2010-07-29 and no updates since then. It was my understanding that with the modular service container in JBoss AS 7 there are no longer any compelling arguments for JBossWeb. You'd just take a JBoss AS and disable the subsystems you don't need.

Comment: @James that is why I asked if he wanted to front jboss with tomcat, it seemed like an odd thing to try.

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall Yes, JBossWeb is still alive. From what I understand at this point it's just essentially a fork of Tomcat without many changes. https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-AS7FAQ

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins the link points to JBoss WebServices, not JBossWeb (they are not related)

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall They sure aren't. Sorry about, I'll chalk it up to a copy/paste error. This is this link I meant to paste http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/.